# Error to resolve ApolloClient (Nuxt.JS 3)

Tags: vuejs3, apollo, apollo-client, nuxtjs3

I have this config on `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  apollo: {
    autoImports: true,
    authType: "Bearer",
    authHeader: "Authorization",
    tokenStorage: "cookie",
    proxyCookies: true,
    clients: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: "...",
      },
      local: {
        httpEndpoint: "...",
      },
    },
  },
  // ...
});
```

Then in my login page I use `useMutation`, that way:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const query = gql`...`;

const { mutate: login } = useMutation<Login>(query);

async function handleSubmit(values) {
  const { onLogin } = useApollo();
  const { cpf, password } = values;

  const variables = { cpf, password };

  const result = await login(variables);

  console.log(result);
}
</script>
```

However when I do try to call `login` callback, application throws this error:
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: No apolloClients injection found, tried to resolve 'default' clientId`

Firtly I installed `@nuxtjs/apollo`, then when I tried to execute a query or mutation I received an error saying that the module `@vue/apollo-composable` was mising.

Then I adressed this github issue: https://github.com/nuxt-modules/apollo/issues/444 and installed the missing module with `npm i --force @vue/apollo-composable`. Now I'm having this error on resolving Apollo clients